# Show favicon-default.png if no favicon available in webview

Tags: android, webview, error-handling, favicon

Okay, so right now I managed how to handle favicons in webview.

But what to do if my webview doesn't receive a favicon? I want to serve a drawable instead named `favicon-default.png`!

How to do this? And where?

Answer (score 0):

If your `webview` does not receive the favicon, call `getResource().getDrawable(R.drawable.favicon_default)`. And please avoid using "-" in drawable name.

Comment: OK, thanks for the hint, Amit! And where to call? Currently my `onReceivedIcon` looks like this: `@Override
            public void onReceivedIcon(WebView view, Bitmap icon) {
             
             view.getUrl();
    favicon.setImageBitmap(icon);
            }`

Comment: if your bitmap icon returns null then call 'getResource().getDrawable(R.drawable.favicon_default)'

Comment: OK, so right now my code looks like this: 
`if(favicon == null)
             {
              Drawable res = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.favicon_default);
              favicon.setImageDrawable(res);
             }
             else
             {
              favicon.setImageBitmap(icon);
             }`

But: when opening a page without a favicon my EditText displays the favicon of the prior page...

Comment: @c1ph4 so could you tell me where it is landing if or else using break point

Comment: yeah, it's landing. I can also see the place holder in the app at this point. There are a lot of tabs open now, please let me know which information you need from where. Starting to list the tabs from up left to down right: Debug, Variables, break point, Activity tab, Outline, Logcat, Console, Tasks, Problems, Executables.

Comment: I mean can you tell me if we are landing at "if" condition or "else" condition where we get the older favicon with this code 'if(favicon == null) { Drawable res = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.favicon_default); favicon.setImageDrawable(res); } else { favicon.setImageBitmap(icon); }'